# Regulating AC Voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, ac

An electrician friend of mine asked me if I could recommend a regulator to step down 125vac down to 118vac with a load of 2.5 amps. He would like 3 amps to be safe.

Normally I deal with low voltage DC and would use a buck-boost regulator to get a very consistent output voltage despite some fluctuation in the input and it has a trimpot for setup/calibration to prevent people from accidentally bumping it or messing with it easily. I don't know if there is a good equivalent for AC loads. Will something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076VKJM42) work, or is there something else that may work better? The load is non-inductive, it is a sensor, so the current draw should be fairly stable. I know we could achieve a roughly similar result with a potentiometer as a voltage divider or a resistor, but we're looking for something more stable and efficient that will adapt to some fluctuation.

Comment: 125V down to 118V is a strange requirement. Is it not within tolerance already? For AC you would typically use a transformer.

Comment: Sounds to me like a job for an [Autotransformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotransformer) or Variac. You could probably scrounge an autotransformer with multiple taps from an old UPS which has AVR functionality.

Comment: The linked device does not change the voltage, it just turns it off some of the time so that the *average* voltage is lower.

Comment: What kind of sensor needs 300W?

Comment: I know of 3 posibilities to convert AC to AC: 1 - transformer, 2 - current converter and 3 - motor–generator (an M–G set).  I doubt you find a (1) with the correct ratio, (2) are not a weekend project, but maybe you can find a device which can do 125 to 118V - maybe even a used one at ebay. (3) easy to build, but I guess it would be hard to find motors with the correct ratio when combined. I know (3) was used at a great scale in Rolling mills for steel production...

Comment: @user253751  Yeah, I would've thought so. I'll ask him again. He seemed to think it was necessary, but it may not be.

Comment: @Finbarr He said it's some sort of air quality particulate sensor.

Comment: An 80A 220V dimmer for $16.99 from a random Amazon seller? What could go wrong? :P

Comment: Get a variac, which will let you adjust it from ~2-130v, they are handy to have around anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpopib.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A step-down transformer arrangement.*

In the arrangement of Figure 1 the secondary voltage can be subtracted or added to the mains voltage depending on which end of the secondary is connected to the live wire. Paying attention to the dot convention shown will result in a voltage reduction. 7 V is not a standard voltage but a 120V:6V transformer should be close enough. Power rating will be 7 V × 2.5 A = 20 VA minimum. I'd go for 30 VA or more.

The whole exercise seems suspect.

- As commented 300 W is a heater, not a sensor.
- 118 V is within the normal variation of 120 V mains supply.
- With the transformer arrangement offered here voltage will vary in proportion to mains voltage.

Constant voltage transformers exist. They (the ones I'm familiar with) use a transformer core with a small air gap and a tertiary winding with a capacitor. The combined effect is to give a fairly constant RMS output voltage although the waveform may be quite distorted.

[image]

*Figure 2. A constant voltage transformer. Image source: [Circuits Today](https://www.circuitstoday.com/cvt-constant-voltage-transformer).*

I don't know if they come in < 1 kVA versions.

Comment: Brilliant cheat!